# Android eclipse , facebook login doesn't proceed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, authentication

I'm still a beginner in programming and I'm trying to make a small project where you can find lists of games and select games for a wishlist. This wishlist I'd like to share on facebook.

The whole facebook SDK works and the login button appears on my app.
Whenever I try to click on the login button, I get "error". As shown in this picture:

[image]

I'm making this login in a Fragment called : wishlistfragmenttab.

This is the code I use for the facebook login.:
The error on the bottom of the picture Is what is programmed in public void onError.

```
  @Override
     public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        loginbutton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_facebook);
        loginbutton.setReadPermissions("email","user_likes","user_friends");
        //loginbutton.setFragment(this);

        loginbutton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override           public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }
                        @Override           public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          }
                        @Override           public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }       });
     }
```

**This is the `onCreate` from `WishlistFragmenttab` :**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


    }
```

**The `Activityresult` from the Fragment :**

```
 @Override  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int
 resultCode, Intent data){      super.onActivityResult(requestCode,
 resultCode, data);
                callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);    }
```

**In `MainActivity` I solved a problemn I got when using `setFragment(this)` . By using :**

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent
 data){         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                wishFragmentTab.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                //callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  }
```

I did put the FacebookActivity in the manifest.
Does anyone know what I still have to do?

Comment: i don't understand, if you are beginning, why are you using eclipse? Anyway, you are apparently receiving an error. did it occurred to you to take a look at what the error could be?

Comment: I'm learning Eclipse in school and I'm trying to create a project with it now :) .
I don't get any errors in the logcat.

But I see people implementing com.facebook.FacebookActivity and com.facebook.LoginActivity in the Manifestfile..

When I'm trying to type com.facebook.LoginActivity in the manifest, It doesn't exist. I'm not sure, but maybe this is one of the problems. I'm still trying to figure it out

Comment: tell your teacher that using eclipse for android is deprecated, and support will end at some point. Any literature you will find from now on is based on android studio.

Comment: You receive a `FacebookException error` object, but you completely ignore it. don't do that.

Comment: You are getting the exception `error` in the `onError()` method. Try to log the actual error to see what you are doing wrong.